# Asp.Net Core Web App Play and download Video from Disk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, asp.net-core, iis

I am having a scenario here. I have to build an asp.net core web application from where I have to browse drive and directories (where hosted: windows) and list the available video files. This portion working perfectly.

Now I have to do two things with those video files:

1. Need to download files (working except the size is < 2 GB)
2. Need to play the video on the page whatever the format and size is.

Asking for your helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can check Asphostportal hosting plan, you can check their shared or VPS plan. They fully support .net core and I believe that they allow you to use videos on their server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**If your website videos, each video is very small, assuming that the video size in a single page does not exceed 100M, or your internet speed is extremely fast, I think your needs are feasible.**

*What I said above is only the content contained in a single page. When there are not many video resources, the page loading speed is related to the bandwidth.*

It is very simple to read files under a certain path, but I think the network speed and the performance of IIS are the bottleneck for reading and downloading.

#### Reason and suggestions

**1. IIS web server just host web application, and also can store some small static resources, such as website pictures, css and js files.**

IIS itself is on windows. When there are not many users, it can run normally by accessing 1G video. It can be loaded slowly. But what if there are many users, such as 100 people or 1000+ people visiting at the same time? I think the pressure on the web server is very high, so your idea is only suitable for a small range of users, and it is recommended that the video resources should not be too large.

**2. I suggest you use third-party media services to store and read videos. For example, use [Azure Media Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/).**

The reason is that if the video resource under the path is read through the web server, it must be very slow in terms of video loading, especially when the file is large and more users access it, the phenomenon will be particularly obvious.

Using Azure Media Services, the opening speed and download speed of playing videos will be improved. As a web server, IIS will no longer bear the pressure of this part of the media service.